# Catch block for (optional) type defined in variable

Tags: powershell, variables, exception, try-catch

I am looking to be able to handle certain exception types differently, and optionally.
If I pass a type to be ignored as an argument `$ignoreExceptionType` I can use

```
try {
   ... code that might generate an exception
} catch {
    if (-not $ignoreExceptionType -or (-not ($PSItem.Exception -is $ignoreExceptionType)) {
        ... do actual exception handling
    }
}
```

However, I wonder if there is a way to have a dedicated `catch` block, something like

```
} catch $ignoreExceptionType {
```

The fact that this variable is optional, and the conditional works fine. But if there is a mechanism to do it as a dedicated block I suspect it could be useful at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the syntax for the `catch` block is restricted to a comma-separated list of 0 or more type names - no variable expansion or other deferable logic can be employed, the list of exception type names has to be hardcoded in the source code.

You can read more about try/catch/finally blocks in the [`about_Try_Catch_Finally` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3#syntax)

Comment: I figured that might be the case. The conditional should work fine, and learning "you can't do that" is still learning. :)